# `GROUP_CONCAT()` for many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables: `types`, `brands` and `type_brand`.

**types**:
`id|title|slug`

**brands**:
`id|title|slug`

and **type_brand**:
`id|type_id|brand_id`

So, I need get all  records from `brands` table with `types` in result column. Like this:

```
id | title | slug | types
1     tit    TIT    type1,type2,type3
```

I write query for this:

```
select brand.title, brand.slug, GROUP_CONCAT(j2.slug) AS types
  from brand brand
LEFT join type_brand j1 on j1.brand_id = brand.id
LEFT join types j2 on j2.id = j1.type_id
limit 10
```

It's works wrong, because get brand that only there is in `type_brand` table.
While I need get **ALL** brands from table `brands` with optional column `types` in result.

Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just need `GROUP BY`?

```
select brand.title, brand.slug, GROUP_CONCAT(j2.slug) AS types
from brand brand LEFT join
     type_brand j1
     on j1.brand_id = brand.id LEFT join
     types j2
     on j2.id = j1.type_id
group by brand.title, brand.slug 
limit 10;
```